# Find a Value in a HashMap mapped to a Key formated as a Regex that matches the given String

Tags: java, regex, string, hashmap

I have a requirement where I need to find the values from the `HashMap` where few keys are stored in **regex** format. For example, some of the keys are in this format
`"abc.\*.xyz"`, `"efg.\*.asc"`.

How do I retrieve the value for `"abc.unset.xyz"`?

Please note that only few keys are in this format. Others may not have dot delimiter at all, and they may be just a single word like `"abc"`. In short, map's keyset contains a mix of both.

Comment: There are no magic solutions here. Iterate over the keys and check whether any of them are a match.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I initially understood the question along the same lines, but then I realized it is simpler than that. It's just a question of converting a key prior to lookup in the map – so if a caller has key `abc.unset.xyz`, they first convert that key string to `abc.*.xyz`. From there, just do `map.get("abc.*.xyz")` which has a result (or not).

Comment: @Kaan Sure, but what if the key is stored as `*.unset.xyz`? Or `abc.unset.*`? Or some other regular expression entirely? If you can reliably predict the format of the regular expression for a given string, then you're back to just regular key lookups and  the entire question becomes moot.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen If we were solving a real problem, I agree those would be valid considerations, but they are beyond what OP asked to solve for. There's a separate real-world consideration with the current problem definition (which I ignored in my answer), but: since the target key name is a pattern basically, how should the app handle similar starting keys? Does one overwrite and win? Do they combine together? Is there a list of results? Example: `"abc.111.xyz"` and `"abc.222.xyz"` – does one win? Do they merge? etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the set of entries of the map either using a loop or a stream and filter out the entry containing a regular expression a key that matches the given string.

Alternatively, you can perform iteration over the set of keys as *@Robby Cornelissen* suggested in the comments, but if you change the type of map let's say to `TreeMap` your code will get an additional cost because accessing the value will no longer be **O(1)**, but **O(log n)**. With entries, you always have direct references to a key and a value together, and retrieving the value would always be **O(1)**.

If you expect only a single target key to be present, then it can be done like that using Stream API:

```
String seachKey = "abc.unset.xyz";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

String values = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> seachKey.matches(entry.getKey()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(); // or .orElse(defaultValue); depending on your needs
```

*Sidenote:* you're note escaping dots in your regular expressions, dot in regex denotes a symbol of any kind. I guess you've probably meant:

`"abc\\..+\\.xyz"` - *"abc"* + *dot* + *one or more symbols*  + *dot* + *"xyz"*

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The keys themselves contain regular expressions.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks, you're right. Updated the answer. I've got the question wrong because in `abc.*.xyz` dots are not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

> *some of the keys are in this format abc.*.xyz, efg.*.asc.*
> *How do i retrieve the value for abc.unset.xyz?*

You are describing a step where you need to take an actual key (such as "abc.unset.xyz") and convert that to it's equivalent "pattern key" (such as "abc.*.xyz"). In some cases, the original key is the same as the "pattern key" in the map (such as "abc").

This sounds like:

- prior to calling `.get()` on your map, convert the key using a function
- that function applies a regular expression to the key value itself, turning a string like "abc.unset.xyz" into a string like "abc.*.xyz"

Here's an example of what that function could look like:

```
public static String getUpdatedKey(String key) {
    return key.replaceAll("\\.[a-z]+\\.", ".*.");
}
```

Here's a simple demo of:

- a map with a literal key "abc.*.xyz"
- caller asking if the long key "abc.unset.xyz" is present (it isn't, print `null`)
- caller getting the updated key, and asking if that is present (it is, print `1`)

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("abc.*.xyz", 1);

String fullKey = "abc.unset.xyz";
System.out.println(map.get(fullKey));

String updatedKey = getUpdatedKey(fullKey);
System.out.println(map.get(updatedKey));
```

Running above prints

```
null
1
```

This example also works if the input key (such as "abc") doesn't contain the other pattern parts:

```
map.put("abc", 2);
System.out.println(map.get(getUpdatedKey("abc")));
```

Running above prints `2`.

You might need to adjust the regular expression in `getUpdatedKey()`, but this seems like a workable format to follow.